# Closed form for the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}‎\frac{\pi^n}{n!n^p}z^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

I know that the following series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}‎\frac{\pi^n}{n!n^p}z^n ;\;z\in\mathbb{C},$$
is convergent by applying the ratio test. Now I wanted to know that Does the series have any closed form. Anyone can help me? Thanks.
Do attention that $p‎>‎1$.

Comment: If $p$ is not zero, start the summation at $n=1$. For $n=0$ and $n=1$, there are closed forms. For $n>1$, you face hypergeometric functions.

Comment: The sum is not well-defined for $p>0$ due to the division-by-zero occurring at the zero-th term. If the sum is modified so as to begin from $n=1$, then for each positive integer $p$, the sum is given in terms of the special function called *exponential integral*.

Comment: @ Sangchul Lee, You are right, I corrected it.

Answer (score 5):

For $p=0$, it is $e^{\pi z}-1$, since
$$
f_0(z) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!} = e^{z}-1
$$
For $p=1$, take $f_0/z$ and integrate
$$
f_1(z) := \int_0^z \frac{f_0(t)}{t}\;dt =  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n! n}
=\mathrm{Ei}(z) - \gamma - \log 2
$$
an "exponential integral" function, and yours is $f_1(\pi z)$.

For $p=2$ repeat,
$$
f_2(z) = \int_0^z\frac{f_1(t)}{t}\;dt
=\mathrm{Ei}\left( z \right)-\log  \left( z \right)+z-{e^{z}}-
\gamma\,z+1
$$
and yours is $f_2(\pi z)$.  Continue
$$
f_3(z) = \int_0^z\frac{f_2(t)}{t}\;dt
$$
still more complicated expression involving $\mathrm{Ei}(z)$.

---

As Claude noted, these may also be written in terms of generalized hypergeometric functions (but this is little more than the definition):

$$
f_p(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!\,n^p} = z\;{}_{p+1}F_{p+1}\!
\left(\begin{align}1,1,\cdots,1\\2,2,\cdots,2\end{align};z\right)
$$

Comment: @ GEdgar, Excuse me, I added a new condition recently.

Comment: @ GEdgar, Would you help me to solve this problem: what is the closed form for this series     $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}‎\frac{\pi^n}{(n+1)!n^2}z^{n+1}$, thanks a lot.